# Cannot find module '@/assets/<file-name-here>.svg'. @vue/cli Version: 4.2.3 and 4.3.1

Tags: vue.js, webpack, import, command-line-interface, assets

### General jist:

```js
import Image from '@/assets/default-profile-picture.svg'
//ERROR: Cannot find module '@/assets/default-profile-picture.svg'.Vetur(2307)
```

I have spent the better part of today trying to find a solution to this. I know there are a lot of other posts like this one, but they are all outdated (all over a year old).

I've just generated a clean Vue CLI app, and still have the same issue.

I'm using Vue CLI Version 4.2.3, and just attempted using Vue CLI Version 4.3.1, but ran into the same issue.

I have checked that the file is in assets. 
I have checked that the filename is spelled correctly.
I have a feeling this is a webpack issue, as require() would not work when called using typescript.
I have tried creating `vue.config.js` and manually setting the path for assets.

### Project setup configuration:

1. Features: Babel, TS, Router, ESLint
2. not class-style syntax
3. Babel used alongside Typescript
4. No history mode for router
5. eslint with error prevention only
6. Lint on save
7. Configs placed in package.json.

## Error in Component.vue

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

/* Cannot find module '@/assets/default-profile-picture.svg'.Vetur(2307) */
import Image from '@/assets/default-profile-picture.svg'

export default Vue.extend({
  components: {
  },
  props: [
    'employeeImage',
    'employeeName',
    'employeeAge',
    'employeeSalary'
  ],
  data () {
    return {
      marked: false,
      result: [],
      name: this.employeeName,
      age: this.employeeAge,
      salary: this.employeeSalary
    }
  },
  computed: {
    compClasses: function () {
      return {
        marked: this.marked
      }
    },
    imageDefault: function () {
      if (this.employeeImage === '') {
        console.log('employee image empty: ' + this.employeeImage)
        return '@/assets/default-profile-picture.svg'
      } else {
        console.log('employee image set: ' + this.employeeImage)
        return this.employeeImage
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

## Typescript Config

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
        "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
        },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "/src/**/*.*",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to be [a Vetur issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/762).  Top voted solution [there](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/762#issuecomment-599272491):  "Manually drag your Vue App's Folder to the top of your opened projects inside of your VS Code workspace."

Comment: @Dan I agree it may be a Vetur issue. I tried your suggestion but alas it hasn't removed the issue.
However, it is showing me more linting details than previously.

Comment: I've updated the main post with my tsconfig.json. 
Here is some helpful info about Vetur:
https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/setup.html#project-setup

... and path mapping in the TypeScript config:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Still on the hunt.

Comment: @NoHara did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep this in mind, that this answer is not a solution but more like a **work-around for this issue** by the time this question has been asked/answered for vue-svg-loader(@vue/cli Version: 4.2.3 and 4.3.1).

You can use **absolute path** instead of using **@** to reference the file when you want to import .vue components. Here is an example:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Read more about this issue and any possible solutions on official repository for this issue on GitHub:
[Typescript Cannot find module '@/assets/svg/register.svg?inline' #92](https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/issues/92)

Comment: Thanks! Do you specifically know why an absolute path has to be used?

Comment: @NoHara, yes, actually Vetur causing the problem, there is an open thread on GitHub for this issue, let's hope they fix it in the next update :)

Comment: If the @ in general does not work, you have a problem with your setup, maybe tsconfig.json. This has nothing to do with importing svg files.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not support **svg** files.
Create a `svg.d.ts` file in your project source folder with the following content:

```
declare module '*.svg';
```

and restart your editor